# Using Glide to cache webview images

Tags: android, caching, webview, kotlin, android-glide

I'd like to use Glide to manage the image resources of my webview, mainly so that I can reuse them later in other views.

I've set up a redirect by intercepting image resource loads and returning the following `WebResourceResponse`:

```
class ImageResponse(view: WebView, url: String) : WebResourceResponse("", "", null) {

    val futureBitmap = GlideApp.with(view).asBitmap().load(url).submit()

    override fun getData(): InputStream {
        val bos = ByteArrayOutputStream()
        futureBitmap.get().compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 0 /*ignored for PNG*/, bos)
        val bitmapdata = bos.toByteArray()
        return ByteArrayInputStream(bitmapdata)
    }
}
```

Ultimately, I create a future loader and use that to cache and return the image as an input stream.

However, this method is significantly slower than the webview's native method (~5s vs ~8s).

This may partly be because Glide has to confirm with the ui thread with each request to make sure that the view is valid before proceeding with the load.

Is there anything that I can do to improve the loading process?

(I'd also like to verify that `submit()` starts loading the resources immediately rather than waiting for `get()` to be called on the future target, but I haven't found a way to add a listener yet and don't see it in the docs)

Comment: I would have assumed the difference is due to the fact that this waits for Glide to finish downloading, decoding, rescaling, and re-encoding the image before providing any data to the WebView, which can normally display images progressively.

Comment: @ephemient decoding/encoding might be an issue, especially since I have to convert it once again in `getData`. `submit` with no arguments should load it with the original sizing. I know that there are caching strategies that do so after the resource is retrieved, so I'll have to look into whether it's done asynchronously after or before `get`